# Select box validation (in laravel)

Tags: php, validation, select, laravel

I have a form containing text inputs and select box. I was trying to apply laravel validation. Now i wanted to retain the user inputted values, if validation doesn't success.

I am able to get this done on input box, but not on select box. How to show previously selected value(in select box) if validation doesn't pass.

This is my code

```
{{Form::select('vehicles_year', $modelYears, '-1', ['id' => 'vehicles_year'])}}

<span class="help-block" id="vehicles_year_error">
    @if ($errors->has('vehicles_year')) {{$errors->first('vehicles_year')}} @endif
</span>
```

-1 is the key of default value that i am showing when the form loads.

Answer (score 2):

What I do is that I add "default" option which value is set to "nothing".
In validation rules I say this value is required. If user does not pick
one of the other options, validation fails.

```
$options = [
    'value' => 'label',
    'value' => 'label',
    'value' => 'label',
    'value' => 'label',
];

$options = array_merge(['' => 'please select'], $options);

{{ Form::select('vehicles_year', $options, Input::old('vehicles_year'), ['id' => 'vehicles_year']) }}

@if ($errors->has('vehicles_year'))
    <span class="help-block" id="vehicles_year_error">
         {{ $errors->first('vehicles_year') }}
    </span>
@endif

// Validation rules somewhere...
$rules = [
    ...
    'vehicles_year' => 'required|...',
    ...
];
```

Answer (score 1):

The controller code is missing. I will suppose your handle the `POST` in a controller method and then you `Redirect::back()->withInput();`

Thanks to `->withInput()` You can use in your view something like `Input::old()` to get the Input values of your previous request.

So to select your previous item `AND` have -1 by default, you can use `Input::old('vehicles_year', -1)`

The first argument is the Input name, and the second is the default value.

```
{{Form::select('vehicles_year', $modelYears, Input::old('vehicles_year', -1), ['id' => 'vehicles_year'])}}
```

Hope this helps